# How to list all members in specified LDAP group

Tags: python, linux, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

Here is my example code of what I am trying to do:

```
server = 'ldap://myserver'

dn = 'uid=username,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com'

base = 'cn=groupName,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com'

pw = "password"
filter = '(objectclass=*)'
attrs = ['member']

con = ldap.initialize(server)

try:
    con.start_tls_s()
    con.simple_bind_s(dn,pw)
    print con.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs)
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
    print "Your username or password is incorrect."
    sys.exit()
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    if type(e.message) == dict and e.message.has_key('desc'):
        print e.message['desc']
    else:
        print e
    sys.exit()
finally:
    print "unbinding."
    con.unbind()
```

I'm doing a `connection.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs)` to simply try and print all the members of a specified group. This sort of works but I get tons of other information about the members. How do I use the filter and attrs variables so the I can get a nice list of only the member uids? My goal is to have the list of uids written into a csv file if possible.

Comment: Tons of information about the *members*? Such as what? This search should only return attributes of the *group* object, and the way you have it, it should only return the `member` attribute.

Comment: And if you already have the group object DN you don't need subtree scope. You can use object scope. In fact you shouldn't need the search either, you should be able to retrieve the attribute directly, although I am no python-ldap expert.

Comment: How would I retrieve it directly ?

Comment: There should be some kind of a lookup API.